# fill pandas values dictionary using list comprehension

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary-comprehension

Is there a way to replace this syntax by a list comprehension?

```
for w in loc:
    dict_filter_data[w] = df.loc[df['location'] == w]
```

If is it possible, would it be faster?

Comment: Does `dict_filter_data` have previous values or does it starts empty ?

Comment: it starts empty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do:

```
dict_filter_data = dict(df.loc[df['location'].isin(loc)]
                          .groupby('location').__iter__()
                       )
```

if `loc` contains all unique `location` values ​​then you just need:

```
dict_filter_data= dict(df.groupby('location').__iter__())
```

note that using groupby here is highly recommended, it is much faster than using a for loop. But you could do:

```
dict_filter_data = {w : df.loc[df['location'] == w] for w in loc}
```

if you want to update `dict_filter_data` **(not start empty)**:

```
dict_filter_data.update(dict(df.loc[df['location'].isin(loc)]
                               .groupby('location').__iter__()
                            )
                       )
```

Or

```
dict_filter_data = dict(dict_filter_data, 
                        **dict(df.loc[df['location'].isin(loc)]
                                 .groupby('location').__iter__()
                              )
                        )
```